# Subscript Out of range VBA Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba. I am trying to copy header row from one sheet to newly created another sheet. I am getting an out of range error when try to select new worksheet. Below is the code i am using.

```
With Sheets("Details Master")
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngsource As Range
    Dim rngDest As Range    

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Details Master")
    'Sheets("Details Master").Select
    Set rngsource = ws1.Range("B2:L2")
    rngsource.Copy
   End With
With Sheets("Sh_name")  **'Error on this line**
   Set ws2 = Sheets("Sh_name") 'Sh_name is newly created sheet name
   Set rngDest = ws2.Range("B2:L2")

    rngDest.PasteSpecial
End With
```

Any idea what might be the issue.

Comment: I ran your code with no issue. Where is your code in the vb editor? in a worksheet or in a module? if in a modeul, you can do this, but if in a specific worksheet you'll need to explicitly state where each sheet is.

Comment: Also try not to copy/paste, and instead just tell the data where to go

Comment: If you get an subscript out of range on `Sheets("Sh_name")` then a sheet with the name  `Sh_name` does not exist. Is there a blank maybe at the end?

Comment: The `With Sheets("Sh_name")` and following `End With` lines are not doing anything and **should be removed.**  You'll still get the error on the next line (`Set ws2 = Sheets("Sh_name")`) if you don't have an existing worksheet by the specified name.  **No worksheets are `newly created` by your code** as indicated by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to add the new worksheet, as @Storax and @ ashleedawg commented.

When using this basic code, please change the new worksheet name from "Temp" to what you want your worksheet name to be. Also make sure the name in the Destination line is the same name.

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"
    Sheets("Details Master").Range("B2:L2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Temp").Range("B2")
End With
```